# Render a Joomla 2.5 Menu Module with some PHP

Tags: joomla, menu, module, render

Trying to use this code to render a menu module on a custom template

```
jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule( 'menu' );
$attribs = array('style' => 'mainnav');
$module->params = "menutype=" .$mainmenu ."\nshowAllChildren=1";
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module, $attribs);
```

The menu only works if I have another menu module published, so I am sure this only needs a line of code to make it work without having to publish a menu module.

The menu exists, the module for this menu does not exist, I am trying to create it with this code.

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code works fine I just had a small correction to make:

```
jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule( 'mod_menu' );
$attribs = array('style' => 'mainnav');
$module->params = "menutype=" .$mainmenu ."\nshowAllChildren=1";
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module, $attribs);
```

on the second line, the call should be to "mod_menu" and not just "menu", and this makes the code to work perfect :)

Comment: That's awesome @Danny I'm glad to hear you made it!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't just use the include module?

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="mainnav" style="mainnav" />
```

This will allow you to publish whatever module you wan't in that position.

Otherwise the `getModule` function works like this:

```
JModuleHelper::getModule( 'position', 'title' );
```

According to the Joomla! API so you need to pass both parameters.

Comment: Sorry I don't need this. I want to select a menu from back-end and the module must be rendered with this code. So again this code almost works.

Comment: Updated to answer what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your effort Antonio. Still this does not help.

This code:

$module->params = "menutype=" .$mainmenu ."\nshowAllChildren=1"; 


is calling a certain menutype and not a module position or a menu/module title, so it cannot work.

Comment: I think it just won't work in the way you want. You need to have a module published to use the `getModule` method.

According the docs a given module would only work if it meets the following criteria:

it is enabled;
it is assigned to the current menu item or is assigned to all menu items;
the user meets the access level requirements.

Comment: It works for sure, it just needs to import a certain class or helper like jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' ); one that is related and used by mod_menu and I am not sure witch one it is.

Comment: I just sticked to documentation which says it won't work and it makes sense. You're trying to render a module which doesn't exist. However, I hope someone could give you the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

i use this code  to render other module by id

```
$mod_id = $params->get('mod_id');
if ($type == 'logout' && $mod_id != ''){
    $document   = &JFactory::getDocument();
    $renderer   = $document->loadRenderer('module');
    $db     =& JFactory::getDBO();

    if ($jVersion=='1.5') {
         $query = 'SELECT id, title, module, position, params'
        . ' FROM #__modules AS m'
        . ' WHERE id='.intval($mod_id);
    } else {
         $query = 'SELECT id, title, module, position, content, showtitle, params'
        . ' FROM #__modules AS m'
        . ' WHERE m.id = '.intval($mod_id);
    }
    $db->setQuery( $query );
    if ($mod = $db->loadObject()){
        $file                   = $mod->module;
        $custom                 = substr( $file, 0, 4 ) == 'mod_' ?  0 : 1;
        $modu->user     = $custom;
    // CHECK: custom module name is given by the title field, otherwise it's just 'om' ??
        $mod->name      = $custom ? $mod->title : substr( $file, 4 );
        $mod->style     = null;
        $mod->position  = strtolower($mod->position);
        echo $renderer->render($mod, array());
     }
}
```

Comment: I think I need something like this, but to get the menu by menutype and render it. I think I will try to do something similar and get back with news here. Thanks :)

Comment: You can see component at http://www.mobilejoomla.com/. They have module like mod_mainmenu for rendering memu on mobile version.

Comment: That thing requires registration and I don't think they have what I need. Remember: the menu exists, the module for this menu does not exist, I am trying to create it with this code.

Comment: Yes. Module from mobile joomla is what your need. Module get items by menu type, and render menu

Comment: Registered MobileJoomla website, downloaded the free version, having a look at the menu module, looks the same as the core mod_menu module. I don't know what exactly I need to copy from this code and add to my code to make it work. Can you please point out what is to do here?

Comment: to get items and render themself as you wish in template.
You can't to render module if it doesn't exists.

Comment: or you can try to select from database some module with mod_mainmenu type, change parameters and render module as in code above.

Comment: Thanks for your input, appreciated! I found the issue and added my answer to this issue, check above.

Answer (score 0):

use this, 100%, render modules at this position.

```
<?php
$document   = &JFactory::getDocument();
$renderer   = $document->loadRenderer('modules');
$options    = array('style' => 'xhtml');
$position   = 'article-banners';
echo $renderer->render($position, $options, null);
?>
```

$position refer to module position, may be more than one...
$style - none, rounded, xhtml...